# Thymeleaf - formatting percentage with only two decimal numbers

Tags: java, formatting, thymeleaf, percentage, bigdecimal

I'm trying to formatting a percentage using Thymeleaf. 
But, with a % like 99.99, thymeleaf formats this value in 100. And I don't want it.

I done this:

**Java side**

```
BigDecimal percentage = (a).multiply(new BigDecimal(100)).divide(b, 3, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
```

**Thymelaf side**

```
th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(percentage, 1, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}"
```

If *percentage* is 99.99 Thymeleaf gives me 100.00

Why?

Answer (score 0):

That happen because your `percentage`'s `scale` value on Java side is greater than `decimalDigits` on Thymeleaf side.

Try to set it the same value (to 2):

```
BigDecimal percentage = (a).multiply(new BigDecimal(100)).divide(b, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
```

And also as if you are using `percentage` field only for showing percentages, I think you don't need `thousandsPointType` parameter (`'POINT'` in your case), because its value will never be greater than 100.